# Static method cannot be referenced from a non static context - trigger before update failing

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, error-messages, static

I understand questions like this have been asked in the past, mostly relating to test classes from what I've seen. I've spent hours trying to find a legitimately applicable question/answer to the problem I'm having, and maybe I'm just a stack exchange rookie but I'm pulling the plug and asking a question of my own.

Getting right to it:

I have a trigger on an object called Product Package (LLC_BI__Product_Package__c) with a corresponding before update handler class to perform an update on the triggering record -- in the future, record*s* hopefully, but it's not yet bulkified. The goal of the handler is to update 5 total values on the triggering record by querying for subtotal values drawn from records of related objects.

Here is the trigger:

```
trigger CreditMemoExposureTrigger on LLC_BI__Product_Package__c (before update) {
    // trigger handler not yet bulkified
    if (Trigger.New.size() == 1) {
        LLC_BI__Product_Package__c triggeringPackage = Trigger.New[0];
        CreditMemoExposureTriggerHandler.updateProductPackage(triggeringPackage);
    }
}
```

here is the handler class: (apologies if the formatting is non-standard)

```
public class CreditMemoExposureTriggerHandler {
    private static Id primaryAccount;
    private static List<LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c> allRelatedEntityInvolvements;
    
    // total exposure variables
    private static double TotalCurrentOutstandingDirect;
    private static double TotalCurrentOutstandingIndirect;
    private static double TotalOriginalAmountDirect;
    private static double TotalRequestedAmountDirect;

    // variables used in total exposure variable formulas
    private static double CurrentOutstandingDirect = 0;
    private static double CurrentOutstandingIndirect = 0;
    private static double OriginalAmountDirectAO = 0;
    private static double OriginalAmountDirectDebt = 0;
    private static double OriginalAmountDirectPrincipal = 0;
    private static double OriginalAmountIndirectDebt = 0;
    private static double PrincipalAmountDirectDebt = 0;
    private static double PrincipalAmountIndirectDebt = 0;
    private static double PrincipalBalanceDirect = 0;
    private static double RequestedAmountDirectAO = 0;
    private static double RequestedAmountDirectPrincipal = 0;
    private static double RequestedAmountIndirect = 0;

    // master method invoked by trigger that will call all child methods in the class
    public static void updateProductPackage(LLC_BI__Product_Package__c TriggerNew) {
        LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c primaryEntityInvolvement = [SELECT Id, LLC_BI__Account__c, LLC_BI__Loan__C
                                                              FROM LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c
                                                              WHERE LLC_BI__Borrower_Type__c = 'Borrower'
                                                              AND LLC_BI__Product_Package__c = :TriggerNew.Id][0];
        primaryAccount = primaryEntityInvolvement.LLC_BI__Account__c;
        allRelatedEntityInvolvements = [SELECT Id, LLC_BI__Account__c, LLC_BI__Loan__c
                                                                        FROM LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c
                                                                        WHERE LLC_BI__Borrower_Type__c = 'Borrower'
                                                                        AND LLC_BI__Account__c = :primaryAccount];
        // run all calculations
        processAllLoans();
        processAllDebt();
        recalculateTotals();

        TriggerNew.Total_Current_Outstanding_Direct__c = TotalCurrentOutstandingDirect;
        TriggerNew.Total_Current_Outstanding_Indirect__c = TotalCurrentOutstandingIndirect;
        TriggerNew.Total_Original_Amount_Direct__c = TotalOriginalAmountDirect;
        TriggerNew.Total_Requested_Amount_Direct__c = TotalRequestedAmountDirect;
        TriggerNew.Total_Requested_Amount_Indirect__c = RequestedAmountIndirect;
    }

    // method to add values from retrieved loan records to terms in total equations
    private static void processAllLoans() {
        // retrieve sets of loans
        Set<LLC_BI__Loan__c> directPrincipalBalanceLoans = getDirectPrincipalBalanceLoans();
        Set<LLC_BI__Loan__c> directAmountOutstandingLoans = getDirectAmountOutstandingLoans();
        Set<LLC_BI__Loan__c> indirectLoans = getIndirectLoans();
        
        // loop through direct principal balance loans
        for (LLC_BI__Loan__c currentLoan : directPrincipalBalanceLoans) {
            PrincipalBalanceDirect += currentLoan.LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c;
            OriginalAmountDirectPrincipal += currentLoan.WMX_Initial_Amount__c;
            RequestedAmountDirectPrincipal += currentLoan.LLC_BI__Amount__c;
        }

        // loop through direct amount outstanding loans
        for (LLC_BI__Loan__c currentLoan : directAmountOutstandingLoans) {
            CurrentOutstandingDirect += currentLoan.LLC_BI__AmountOutstanding__c;
            OriginalAmountDirectAO += currentLoan.WMX_Initial_Amount__c;
            RequestedAmountDirectAO += currentLoan.LLC_BI__Amount__c;
        }

        // loop through indirect loans
        for (LLC_BI__Loan__c currentLoan : indirectLoans) {
            CurrentOutstandingIndirect += currentLoan.LLC_BI__AmountOutstanding__c;
            RequestedAmountIndirect += currentLoan.LLC_BI__Amount__c;
        }
    }

    // method to add values from retrieved debt records to terms in total equations
    private static void processAllDebt() {
        // retrieve sets of debt
        List<LLC_BI__Debt__c> directDebt = getDirectdebt();
        List<LLC_BI__Debt__c> indirectDebt = getIndirectDebt();

        // loop through direct debt
        for (LLC_BI__Debt__c currentDebt : directDebt) {
            PrincipalAmountDirectDebt += currentDebt.LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c;
            OriginalAmountDirectDebt += currentDebt.LLC_BI__Original_Amount__c;
        }

        // loop through indirect debt
        for (LLC_BI__Debt__c currentDebt : indirectDebt) {
            PrincipalAmountIndirectDebt += currentDebt.LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c;
            OriginalAmountIndirectDebt += currentDebt.LLC_BI__Original_Amount__c;
        }
    }

    // method to get all direct principal balance loans
    private static Set<LLC_BI__Loan__c> getDirectPrincipalBalanceLoans() {
        return new Set<LLC_BI__Loan__c> {
            [SELECT Id, LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c, LLC_BI__Amount__c, WMX_Initial_Amount__c, LLC_BI__Account__c 
            FROM LLC_BI__Loan__c
            WHERE LLC_BI__Stage__c != 'Complete'
            AND LLC_BI__Product__c NOT IN ('ACH Debit Exposure', 'RDC Exposure')
            AND LLC_BI__Structure_Hierarchy__c != 'Current Takedown'
            AND LLC_BI__hasRenewal__c = false
            AND (
                LLC_BI__Product__c LIKE '%Term%'
                OR LLC_BI__Product__c IN ('Agriculture', 'Commercial')
            )
            AND Id IN (SELECT LLC_BI__Loan__c 
                       FROM LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c 
                       WHERE Id IN :allRelatedEntityInvolvements)]
        };
    }

    // method to get all direct amount outstanding loans
    private static Set<LLC_BI__Loan__c> getDirectAmountOutstandingLoans() {
        return new Set<LLC_BI__Loan__c> {
            [SELECT Id, LLC_BI__AmountOutstanding__c, LLC_BI__Amount__c, WMX_Initial_Amount__c, LLC_BI__Account__c 
            FROM LLC_BI__Loan__c
            WHERE LLC_BI__Stage__c != 'Complete'
            AND LLC_BI__Product__c NOT IN ('ACH Debit Exposure', 'RDC Exposure')
            AND LLC_BI__Structure_Hierarchy__c != 'Current Takedown'
            AND LLC_BI__hasRenewal__c = false
            AND (NOT LLC_BI__Product__c LIKE '%Term%')
            AND LLC_BI__Product__c NOT IN ('Agriculture', 'Commercial')
            AND Id IN (SELECT LLC_BI__Loan__c 
                       FROM LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c 
                       WHERE Id IN :allRelatedEntityInvolvements)]
        };
    }

    // method to get all indirect loans
    private static Set<LLC_BI__Loan__c> getIndirectLoans() {
        return new Set<LLC_BI__Loan__c> {
            [SELECT Id, LLC_BI__AmountOutstanding__c, LLC_BI__Amount__c, WMX_Initial_Amount__c, LLC_BI__Account__c 
            FROM LLC_BI__Loan__c
            WHERE LLC_BI__Stage__c != 'Complete'
            AND LLC_BI__hasRenewal__c = false
            AND LLC_BI__Product__c IN ('ACH Debit Exposure', 'RDC Exposure')
            AND Id IN (SELECT LLC_BI__Loan__c 
                       FROM LLC_BI__Legal_Entities__c 
                       WHERE Id IN :allRelatedEntityInvolvements)]
        };
    }

    // method to get all direct debt
    private static List<LLC_BI__Debt__c> getDirectDebt() {
        return [SELECT Id, LLC_BI__Original_Amount__c, LLC_BI__Available_Amount__c, LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c
                FROM LLC_BI__Debt__c
                WHERE LLC_BI__Account__c = :primaryAccount
                AND Excluded_From_Exposure__c = false
                AND LLC_BI__Exposure_Type__c IN ('Direct', 'ACH Credit, Derivative, FX, Overdraft Direct Exposure')];
    }

    // method to get all indirect debt
    private static List<LLC_BI__Debt__c> getIndirectDebt() {
        return [SELECT Id, LLC_BI__Original_Amount__c, LLC_BI__Available_Amount__c, LLC_BI__Principal_Balance__c
                FROM LLC_BI__Debt__c
                WHERE LLC_BI__Account__c = :primaryAccount
                AND Excluded_From_Exposure__c = false
                AND LLC_BI__Exposure_Type__c IN ('Direct', 'RDC Exposure', 'ACH RDC Exposure', 'ACH Credit, Derivative, FX, Overdraft Indirect Exposure')];
    }

    // method to recalculate total exposure levels
    private static void recalculateTotals() {
        TotalCurrentOutstandingDirect = CurrentOutstandingDirect + PrincipalAmountDirectDebt + PrincipalBalanceDirect;
        TotalCurrentOutstandingIndirect = CurrentOutstandingIndirect + PrincipalAmountIndirectDebt;
        TotalOriginalAmountDirect = OriginalAmountDirectAO + OriginalAmountDirectDebt + OriginalAmountDirectPrincipal;
        TotalRequestedAmountDirect = RequestedAmountDirectAO + RequestedAmountDirectPrincipal;
    }
}
```

any time we attempt to save a trivial update to an LLC_BI__Product_Package__c record to trip the trigger, we get the error "Static method cannot be referenced from a non static context". I have declared every single possible class-level variable and class method as static so I have positively no idea why this would be the case.

Just hoping someone can answer before I break this company laptop and they fire me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error message as well as the stack trace for your error (the part that tells you which line in which class the failure happened). Paraphrasing and/or omitting information from the error message makes it harder to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: I am having difficulty obtaining debug logs for the issue. I have set up trace flags on both the trigger and the handler class, but when I try to save a change on the record page layout in Salesforce and I receive the error, I do not see any debug logs generating.

Comment: Is your trigger in a package or just on the org? If part of a package you have to use subscriber access to get debug info from within the package. If you do not get debug info outside a package, are you setting up the user trace against the correct user and with the right debug settings?

Comment: The trigger is not part of a package, it was built in-house. My previous statement was misguided.... I did not see that a different developer on my team had added a couple of statements to *another* trigger which was causing the error that I was seeing before the trigger of concern was even being reached. I am not seeing a different error that does not have to do with static methods be un-referenceable. I will return to this post with additional questions if I get stuck again.